# In NaCl electrolysis, why does chlorine ion get oxidized but not oxygen ion?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, electrolysis

In $\ce{NaCl}$ electrolysis, on the positive electrode (aka. on the electrode where oxidation happens), $\ce{Cl-}$ ions are oxidized to $\ce{Cl2}$. But why don't we see any $\ce{O^2-}$ (naturally present in water's $\ce{OH-}$ ions) oxidized to $\ce{O^2}$ at all?

**My pre-existing knowledge, may or may not be correct, that led to this question:**
[1] I am under the impression that chemical reaction is a messy business in the real-world with many reactions reversible, many intermediary steps happening and many small reactions happening in the sideways. So the real-world scenario is never as neat as one clean equation.

[2] I am aware of the concept of electronegativity, and I also have feelings that
$\ce{O^2-}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ should require a similar amount of energy input to get them oxidized. So we should really expect both reactions to happen.

With my pre-existing knowledge laid out above, I find it remarkable that not a trace of $\ce{O^2-}$ is oxidized at all. This led me to guess that the $\ce{OH-}$ ion itself may have imparted some degree of protection to the $\ce{O^2-}$ inside of it?

Comment: You would get dioxygen if the concentration of chloride in the vicinity of the electrode were so low that you preferentially oxidized water instead. Depending on the nature of your cell and the concentrations involved, this may or may not happen.

Comment: @Zhe But there seems to be a strong preference for Cl- to be oxidized first.

Comment: There is. But that can only happen if it's there. If you locally deplete chloride, and it's not replaced quickly, then you'll oxidize something else.

Comment: Eliu: Your observation relative to chlorine is correct. For an accurate technical answer, see my comments below, which I would recommend for extra points if you have to explain your experimental results. Else, more simple, and perhaps appropriate for a less advanced course argument, is espoused by my esteemed colleagues below.

Comment: @AJKOER I took one course in chemistry, an university first year 101, my whole life. I was initially just trying to understand fermi levels in semi conductors. But, one digression after another... and here I am. Who knew that a simple action of bumping an electron out of place can lead to soooo many equations and disciplines, microscopic and macroscopic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that as stated in another answer there is no *simultaneous* evolution of oxygen or chlorine during controlled electrolysis. It all depends on the concentration of ions in the solution. Keep in mind that the concentration of water is 55 M, so the ion concentration is nowhere near it no matter what you do!

The key reason is that the electrode potential of chlorine/chloride couple is quite different from that of oxidation of water, so if you have a high concentration of chloride ion, chlorine is oxidized first, once chlorine falls below a certain threshold, water begins to oxidize. Nernst equation can help in predicting that.

Answer (score 5):

I agreed with explanation given by M. Farooq. However, since OP is really a novice to the field, I'd like to clear some point for OP's benefit.

The electrolysis cell has 3 species ($\ce{Na+}$, $\ce{Cl-}$, and $\ce{H2O}$), each of which can be either oxidized or or reduced. $\ce{Na+}$ can only be reduced while $\ce{Cl-}$ can be only oxidized. Water is a unique species, which can be either oxidized or reduced based on the situation:

Relevant reduction half-reactions:

$$\ce{2 Na+ + e- <=> Na^0_{(s)}} \qquad E^\circ = \pu{-2.71 V} \tag{1}$$

$$\ce{2 H2O + 2e- <=> H2_{(g)} + 2OH- } \qquad E^\circ = \pu{-0.828 V} \tag{2}$$

Relevant oxidation half-reactions:

$$\ce{2 Cl- <=> Cl2_{(g)} + 2e-} \qquad E^\circ = \pu{-1.358 V} \tag{3}$$

$$\ce{2 H2O <=> O2_{(g)} + 4H+ + 4e-} \qquad E^\circ = \pu{-1.229 V} \tag{4}$$

Since $E^\circ$ of all four half-reactions are negative, this need external power source. That's why it is electrolytic cell. We can eliminate reduction of $\ce{Na+}$, because it need extra power to proceed ($\ce{Na+}$ can be reduced if you use molten $\ce{NaCl}$). Thus electrolytic cell would be combinations of either equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ or equations $(2)$ and $(4)$:

$$\ce{2 H2O + 2Cl- <=> H2_{(g)} + Cl2_{(g)} + 2OH- } \qquad E^\circ_
\mathrm{EMF} = \pu{-2.186 V} \tag{5}$$

$$\ce{2 H2O  <=> 2H2_{(g)} + O2_{(g)} } \qquad E^\circ_
\mathrm{EMF} = \pu{-2.057 V} \tag{6}$$

The $E^\circ_\mathrm{EMF}$ value of equations $(5)$ and $(6)$ are so close that either redox reaction can happen with an electrolytic cell consists of dilute $\ce{NaCl}$ solution and a $\pu{3 V}$ battery.

Now consider the The Nernst Equation:

$$E = E^\circ - \frac{RT}{nF}\ln Q =E^\circ - \frac{2.303RT}{nF}\log_{10} Q $$

For equations $(5)$, $Q=\frac{[\ce{OH-}]^2}{[\ce{Cl-}]^2[\ce{H2O}]^2}$ and $n=2$, thus:

$$E_5 = E_5^\circ - \frac{2.303RT}{nF}\log_{10} Q = E_5^\circ - \frac{2.303RT}{2F}\log_{10} \frac{[\ce{OH-}]^2}{[\ce{Cl-}]^2[\ce{H2O}]^2}\\ = -2.186 + \frac{2.303RT}{2F}\log_{10} [\ce{OH-}]^2 [\ce{Cl-}]^2 - \frac{2.303RT}{2F}\log_{10} [\ce{H2O}]^2 \tag{7}$$

For equations $(6)$, $Q=\frac{1}{[\ce{H2O}]^2}$ and $n=4$, thus:

$$E_6 = E_6^\circ - \frac{2.303RT}{nF}\log_{10} Q = E_6^\circ - \frac{2.303RT}{4F}\log_{10} \frac{1}{[\ce{H2O}]^2}\\ = -2.057 + \frac{2.303RT}{4F}\log_{10} [\ce{H2O}]^2  \tag{8}$$

Accordingly, it is possible to increase $[\ce{Cl-}]$ such that, $E_5 \lt E_6$. As a result, redox reaction $(5)$ will predominate. As a reaction progress, $[\ce{Cl-}]$ decreases and at one point, redox reaction $(6)$ will predominate again.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer. Not for the OP though, Bard & Faulkner cringe at changing the sign of the electrode potential because they correctly say that sign of the electrode potential is invariant (it is an electrostatic sign). I also buy this argument after discussing this with a couple of leading electrochemists. I know changing the signs was taught in universities for oxidation potentials in 1970s / 80s books. What is your school of thought?

Comment: Now, I felt duty bound to try to understand what this Nernst equation is about. Also just by eye balling the equations, my summary is that, there are two ways to control what's get oxidized: Voltage threshholding and species concentration.

Comment: @M. Farooq: I'm one of those guys who learnt from those 70/80s books. I'm an organic  chemist who didn't get chance to learn those new concepts. Yet, I still think this way is easy to explain for novices without making it complicated. I hope you'd use your techniques in next time so we all can learn. I'm eager to learn them. Thanks for your kind comments. :-)

Comment: Mathew: Nice argument but it may be technically not appropriate to explain experimental results. So, in the context of test questions for those studying electrolysis, OK,  but I would not dogmatically assert it relating to lab work or advanced graduate studies.

Answer (score 2):

A technical and commercially significant point has not been cited. It directly speaks as to why, in contravention of the comparative electrode potentials (and perhaps even a Nernst concentration equation argument already presented) that **chlorine** is actually created over oxygen. [To quote a source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overpotential):

> Bubble overpotential is a specific form of concentration overpotential and is due to the evolution of gas at either the anode or cathode. This reduces the effective area for current and increases the local current density. An example is the electrolysis of an aqueous sodium chloride solution—although oxygen should be produced at the anode based on its potential, bubble overpotential causes chlorine to be produced instead, which allows the easy industrial production of chlorine and sodium hydroxide by electrolysis.

Answer (score 1):

Both reactions happen at the anode, the proportion of which depends on the concentrations and of the nature of the electrode. The two reactions are :
$$\ce{2 Cl^- -> Cl_2 + 2 e^-}$$
$$\ce{2 H_2O -> 4 H+ + O_2 + 4 e^-}$$
The proportion of the second equation is reduced by using concentrated $\ce{NaCl}$ solutions and electrodes covered by Ruthenium. But there are no ions $\ce{O^{2-}}$ in water and in all its solutions

Comment: There are no O2-, but there are O2- in (OH)-. does (OH)- somehow shield O2-?

Comment: @eliu. Sorry! I do not understand your question ...

Comment: I meant, the O in (OH)-, the hydroxy group, is an ion. Does the hydroxy group somehow prevents O in it to be oxidized?